# Problem with reindex terminal

Tags: magento2, reindex, cli

I have an issue with the reindex of Magento.
I have try to do this with the terminal and this is the response error

```
  [Exception]                                                                  
  Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJ  
  NDAEL_256' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magentooo/vendor/magento/framework/  
  Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 394
```

Is there somebody who can help me with this issue?

Comment: please check mcrypt is installed or not :: php -m | grep mcrypt

Comment: @AdityaShah I checked if the mcrypt is loaded and this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 does not support PHP 7.2. Are you using PHP 7.2? If so, mcrypt is disabled in that version and Magento 2 doesn't yet fully support libsodium, its replacement.

There is a github for that however: https://github.com/magento-engcom/php-7.2-support.

Comment: No I use MAMp 5.1 with PHP 7.1.20